# Saving pandas dataframe to django model with logic to avoid storing duplicate entries for a field in database

Tags: python, django, pandas

How can we add some logic to avoid duplicate entries for the incoming data. For example I am able to save the excel file in my database using to_sql. I have to validate that no two duplicate entries can be created for a column in this case I have title column and validate if two products have same title or name, the entry does not get added to the database.

```
import pandas as pd
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from store.models import Product
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from django.conf import settings

class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = "A command to add data from an Excel file to the database"

  def handle(self, *args, **options):

    excel_file = 'Product_data.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    
    #connection to mysql
    user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
    password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
    database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

    database_url = 'mysql://{user}:{password}@localhost:3306/{database_name}'.format(user=user,password=password,database_name=database_name)

    engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)

    df.to_sql(Product._meta.db_table, if_exists='append', con=engine, index=False)
```

So I have to add the validation logic before the data is inserted into the database such that in my case, we cannot store duplicate products that have same title or product_name.